# OptaPlanner custom score definitions deprecated - how should I implement this in future?

Tags: optaplanner

I have a custom score defined as follows:

```
@PlanningScore(scoreDefinitionClass = MyCustomScoreDefinition.class)
private MyCustomScore score;
```

However the  `scoreDefinitionClass` field is now deprecated. How should custom scores be implemented going forward?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Custom scores are a deprecated feature and we do not expect anyone implementing it anymore. The current selection of scores has been enough for all the use cases we have seen so far.

That said, if you have a use case where none of the built-ins suffice, we'd definitely love to hear about it. [Come find us](https://www.optaplanner.org/community/getHelp.html) and let's discuss.

Comment: Thanks. In our case we are using custom scores to implement pareto scoring. I have started a discussion in the group :)

Comment: Pareto scoring is one seriously good argument indeed for custom score definitions... Discussion in the google group linked above.